# Push object from search using Angular 2 into array

Tags: javascript, angular

I created this search function that hits an API and generates results. I am now trying to push my found result on click to an array.  How do I link a particular selection to my ngModel?

My old way was manual text:

```
<input type="text" class="form-control" placeholder="Angular" [(ngModel)]="company.technology[i].stack" name="technology_{{i}}" #technology="ngModel" required>
```

function to push:

```
onAddStack() {
   this.company.technology.push({stack: ''});
}
```

My new search feature:

```
 <input (keyup)="$event.target.value && searchTerm$.next($event.target.value)">
    <ul *ngIf="results">
     <a *ngFor="let result of results | slice:0:7" class="other" (click)="onAddStack()">
    <li>{{ result.name }}</li>
    </a>
 </ul>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Pass the `result` into the `click` event handler

```
<a *ngFor="let result of results | slice:0:7" class="other" (click)="onAddStack(result)">
   <li>{{ result.name }}</li>
</a>
```

and in the handler push the passed parameter into the array

```
onAddStack(result) {
   this.company.technology.push(result);
}
```